# No encuentro mi error en código c++ sobre colas (queue) usando librería std

Tags: c++

Tengo un error en un código que estoy haciendo en c++ de colas usando la librería estandard, pero no sé cual es exactamente. El código me compila pero se cuelga y no responde. En el código utilice punteros, estructuras y una cola (queue). Se supone que tengo que hacer dos colas simulando personas, son colocadas en una cola C1 si la persona tiene número de DNI impar y si no es derivada a una cola C2 (número de DNI par). De cada persona se conoce: apellido, nombre, edad y DNI.

Dicho código es:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    struct datosCliente
    {
        string nombre;
        string apellido;
        int edad;
        int DNI;
    };

    struct datosCliente *datos;

    datos= new datosCliente;

    (datos+1)->nombre="Diana";
    (datos+1)->apellido = "Garcia";
    (datos+1)->edad=24;
    (datos+1)->DNI=9345781;

    (datos+2)->nombre = "Carlos";
    (datos+2)->apellido = "Garcia";
    (datos+2)->edad=22;
    (datos+2)->DNI=23123984;

    (datos+3)->nombre ="Maria"; 
    (datos+3)->apellido = "Perez";
    (datos+3)->edad=34;
    (datos+3)->DNI=23498892;

    queue <string> C1;
    queue <string> C2;

    string n;
    for(int i = 1; i<= 4; i++){
        ((datos+i)->nombre)=n;
        if ((datos+i)->DNI % 2 == 0)
        C2.push(n); 
        else
        C1.push(n);
        cout<<endl<<endl;}

    cout << "Hay actualmente " << C1.size () << " personas en la cola1" << endl
         << "La primera persona en la cola es " << C1.front () << endl
         << "La ultima persona en la cola es " << C1.back () << endl << endl;

    while(!C1.empty()){
        cout<<"   " <<C1.front()<<endl;
        C1.pop();                          
    }  cout<<"   ";

    cout << "Hay actualmente " << C2.size () << " personas en la cola2" << endl
         << "La primera persona en la cola es " << C2.front () << endl
         << "La ultima persona en la cola es " << C2.back () << endl << endl;

    while(!C2.empty()){
        cout<<"   " <<C2.front()<<endl;
        C2.pop();                          
    }  cout<<"   ";

    system("pause");
}
```

No sé si es que estoy "sobre cargando" o algo por el estilo. Como dije anteriormente sé que tengo un error pero no lo puedo ubicar.

Comment: Tienes un pequeño lío de conceptos. Tu código contiene errores graves que pueden dar lugar a errores en tiempo de compilación. Repasa los conceptos de punteros y el operador `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
datos= new datosCliente;
```

Ahí estás reservando memoria para un único elemento... sin embargo:

```
(datos+1)->nombre="Diana";
/ ...

(datos+2)->nombre = "Carlos";
// ...

(datos+3)->nombre ="Maria"; 
// ...
```

Estás tratando esa reserva como si tuviese al menos 4 elementos. Esto implica que estás escribiendo en memoria que no pertenece a la reserva inicial, por lo que puedes estar sobreescribiendo otras variables de tu aplicación sin darte cuenta.

Para empezar, los índices en C++ empiezan **siempre** en 0. El primer elemento se encuentra en el índice 0, no en el índice 1. En segundo lugar, para reservar memoria para una colección de N elementos tienes que usar `new[]`:

```
datos = new datosCliente[3]; // Reserva para 3 elementos
```

El acceso a los datos puede quedar así (más natural en el lenguaje C++):

```
datos[0].nombre="Diana";
// ...

datos[1].nombre = "Carlos";
// ...

datos[2].nombre ="Maria"; 
// ...
```

Seguimos:

```
for(int i = 1; i<= 4; i++){
    ((datos+i)->nombre)=n;
```

Otro error relacionado con los índices. Ahí estás escribiendo en el rango 1..4 (4 elementos), cuando se supone que tu únicamente tienes 3 elementos. El rango correcto debería ser 0..2 (3 elementos)

```
for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++)
```

Por otro lado, en cada iteración estás sustituyendo el campo `nombre` de cada registro por el contenido de `n`, que es una cadena a la que no le has asignado valor alguno... en pocas palabras, estás borrando todos los nombres. En tal caso la asignación debería ser al revés:

```
for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++){
  n = datos[i].nombre;
```

Comment: Se te ha olvidado comentar que en C++ no es necesario anteponer `struct` al declarar variables de tipo objeto ;) (`struct datosCliente *datos;`).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no, no se me ha olvidado jejeje. Pero si ponía eso me sentía obligado a poner también que falta el `delete[]`, a que en vez de usar el arreglo es mejor usar `std::vector`,  a que las estructuras es mejor declararlas fuera de la función, a que.... y entonces la respuesta acababa desvirtuada

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me ha servido de mucho! :)